# how to fix error laravel 7 array to conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

in blade code

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-11">
              <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" name="title[]"
                id="title_input" value="{{ old('title') }}" autocomplete="name" autofocus
                placeholder="Masukan Title">
            </div>
```

in controller code

```
public function insert(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    if(isset($request->title) && $request->title){
        foreach ($data['title'] as $key => $value) {
            $faqs = new Faqs();
            $faqs->title = json_encode($value);
            $faqs->description = $request->description;
            $faqs->course_id = $request->course_id;
            $faqs->save();
        }
    }
    dd($faqs);
}
```

in model code

```
    class Faqs extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'faqs';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'course_id'];

    
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }
    
}
```

I want to enter the title of more than one data, when I code it above, there is an error like this. How do I fix the error?

```
ErrorException
Array to string conversion.
```

Comment: `dd($data)` and update your question

Comment: If you tell us in which line the error is showing it will be lot easier for us to point you out the error and give the `dd($data)` .too

Comment: Also do `dd($value)` there might be an entire array in the $value

Comment: Which line does you code fail on and dd($data);